# How I access asset folder?

Tags: android

I need to load image from assets in folder like this

[my folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIfOb.png)

and my code just check that how i can access my folder (sorry from poor coding)

```
  public Bitmap test3(){

Bitmap bitmap = null;
AssetManager assManager = null;
try {
    InputStream is = assManager.open("train/c00/Astb412_400_30_18_161.bmp");
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
    return bitmap;
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

    return bitmap;
}
```

So, I just test debug to see but it didn't work
[test debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVVh6.png)

I don't know how I access file. please help

- I should put my folder in res or asset which one is better?
- Can I path folder by string path (I've tried it but didn't work for me)

Comment: Please post any error message as text.

Comment: You have no assets manager.

Answer (score 0):

Better and most suitable way is to put your asset in res folder. After that you can assess them like this.

```js
Drawable image = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.your_file_name_goes_here);
```

Comment: No this is not better and does not address the problem.